# Why in foundry I got lib/forge-std/lib folder empty?

Tags: foundry

Hey Everyone I initialize foundry framework and got folder structures however initially lib folder was missing which i later installed via this command git submodule add --force --name lib/forge-std https://github.com/foundry-rs/forge-std lib/forge-std.Now when i try to run test on my smart contract I came to know that lib/forge-std/lib folder is completely empty whereby my test failed to run how can i get all the files and folders that lies under lib/forge-std/lib ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you're in the correct working directory, and try:

```bash
forge install foundry-rs/forge-std
```

Or you can also try running:

```bash
foundryup
```

Comment: ThankYou It worked

Comment: I also found the other solution to it which was a command as forge install --no-commit which also solved the problem